# R, Elasticsearch : Error: 400 - mapper [a] of different type, current_type [date], merged_type [text]

Tags: r, elasticsearch

Tried to create a document in local elasticsearch instance. But faced the following error.

```
library( elastic )

connect()

docs_create( index = as.character( Sys.Date() ) , type = 'input_json_10', id = '1', body = list( 'a' = list( Sys.Date(), "-0.022461" ) ) )
```

Output I am getting

```
Error: 400 - mapper [a] of different type, current_type [date], merged_type
```

How to solve this error ?

Comment: what version of `elastic` pkg and what version of Elasticsearch?

Comment: It's complaining that the values are of different types in your body, Elasticsearch detects two different types and complains. If the `body` value is `list( 'a' = list( "-0.022461" ) )` it works, and then you can do `list( 'a' = list( Sys.Date(), "-0.022461" ) )` after that - i assume because it just treats the date and number both as text